# How to get Emmet to autocomplete self-closing tags with ' / ' in visual studio code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

So Emmet's autocomplete for HTML tags is very useful but when I want to write a self closing tag like `<br/>` it autocomplete it to `<br>`. I understand that this isn't a big issue at all because it is completely supported, but I like being able to see directly that the tag is closed.

Is there a way to change this behavior in visual studio code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Doing some more research I managed to find this setting to add into `setting.json`

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "html": {
        "self_closing_tag" : true
    }
}
```

Now, writing `br` will autocomplete to `<br/>`

Comment: Thanks. You can also just add / before tabbing for emmet.

Comment: @Pefington you're the best! Regarding self_closing_tag, is there any way to specify this just for some elements?

Comment: @ElliottMejia I don't know about that, but I mean, it's just one forward slash to type ;p